# STM32H7 hangs when trying to erase bank 1, sector 0 shortly after reset

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

Using an STM32H753, I have boot code in bank 1, sector 0 (`0x08000000`) that detects and jumps to application code in bank 2, sector 0 (`0x08100000`). In the application code I am trying to erase and rewrite bank 1 sector 0, but the MCU locks up (with no fault handler output) when I set `FLASHH7_CR_START` too soon after reset.

The application code is quite sophisticated and enables many features of the chip, but neither bank swapping nor FLASH CRC. The fault handler is known to work.

Things I have tried:

- busy wait 50-100ms from reset before erasing; succeeds
- redirect erase/rewrite to bank 1, sector 5; succeeds (without busy wait)
- application code leaves caches disabled; still fails
- compare FLASHH7 register bank at reset and 100ms later; no change
- check errors in `SR` and clear any detected with `CCR`; no errors found
- check `WRP` and `PRAR` registers; no protection set
- check errata rev6 (19 Jun 2019); no relevant issues

The boot code does not enable any interrupts or caches and the application code writes to `VTOR`.

It seems there is something else time-sensitive about erasing the STM32H7 boot sector (or recently executed sector). What am I missing?

Comment: IMO it is a very fresh micro and rather complex as well. I would be surprised if there are no errors in the silicon. Did you check the errata? Report to the STM

Comment: @P__J__ thanks, I'd already reviewed errata rev6 (now noted above) hence avoiding bank swap and CRC

Comment: All interrupt handlers are in RAM ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean no they're in bank 2 flash

Comment: Did you try to copy the flash erasing code to RAM ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean not yet, that would be an interesting experiment (as would be moving the application code to bank 2, sector 1) although the busy wait workaround would still be puzzling

Comment: BTW what do you mean exactly by "the MCU locks up" ?

Comment: If I add ```puts("hi"); while(true);``` just before the write to FLASHH7_CR_START, then I see output on the debug uart. If I move that code to just after the write to START then nothing is output to the uart (not even any fault handler output). Also after failure, if I comment out the erase, then reprogram the app code, then there is no output on reset until I have also reprogrammed the boot code. So it looks like the early write to START causes some combination of stall/fault and that the boot sector is either erased or left with an ECC error.

Answer (score 3):

Posting as an answer because of the image.

As I suspected. Probably silicon bug

[image]

this from the errata pages. Check your uC model (which you actually hide :) )and download errata for your one.

Comment: The question explicitly states that bank swapping is **not enabled**.

Comment: But it looks anyway as another bug

Comment: It's an STM32H753 and I've checked errata rev6. Already avoiding bank swapping. Will try to work up minimal repro code.

Comment: Did you contact STMicro support directly ? They might be quite helpful on such topics.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean yes, waiting to hear back from STM